# How to start GNOME temporarily with a different GUI language with Wayland?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, locale, gnome-shell, wayland

I know [how to start a GNOME session in a console tty under Wayland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51235031/5008962) ([original source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Wayland_sessions)) and also the `LANG=en-US` trick that usually works in Linux applications.

Now from the previously linked source I tried this command:

```
LANG=en-US XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session
```

It did not work and returned me [some errors](https://gist.github.com/rugk/a7dafed2f0f97471ae01cfed5636a2e5) ending with:

```
fusermount: failed to access mountpoint /run/user/1000/gvfs: Permission denied
A connection to the bus can't be made
```

Running it with my system's configured language did work, however.

My **use case** is just that I'd like to make screenshots of some GNOME built-in messages/GUI elements itself (that are not part of any program, such as `gnome-control-center`. To be more useful (for an international reader/viewer) I'd like to get/use the English version of these. Temporarily of course, I am not keen on changing my system's language in the settings back and forth. Usually that way with `LANG=en-US` it works so smoothly.

---

This question [has been cross-posted on ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/128016/how-to-start-gnome-temporarily-with-a-different-gui-language-with-wayland/).

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)... For your use case you just launch the program with the desired locale in your current session e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gnome-control-center` and you'll get g-c-c with `en_US` interface...

Comment: Well… be assured that in my case, it was really about GNOME/the actual gnome-shell. Nevertheless, a good tip. :)

Comment: I actually explicitly stated that it e.g. is _not_ `gnome-control-center`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution [has been posted on AskFedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/128016/how-to-start-gnome-temporarily-with-a-different-gui-language-with-wayland/?answer=128021#post-id-128021) by [@johanh](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/users/14360/johanh/):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF8 dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --display-server --wayland
```